# System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists. in sssi pack

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I deploy the pack from ssis to SSISD, and try to create agent job to run the package.

after deploy to SSMS, getting the error

System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.

===================================

An entry with the same key already exists. (System)

---

Program Location:

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.TreeSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T item)
   at System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcCollatedDictionaryCollection`3.AddShadow(T obj)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcCollection`3.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ISfcCollection.AddShadow(SfcInstance sfcInstance)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcInstance.CreateNewObjectFromRow(ISfcCollection childColl, IDataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcInstance.InitObjectsFromEnumResultsRec(ISfcCollection childColl, IDataReader reader, Int32 columnIdx, Object[] parentRow)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcInstance.InitObjectsFromEnumResults(ISfcCollection childColl, IDataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcInstance.InitChildLevel(ISfcCollection childColl)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcCollection`3.InitializeChildCollection(Boolean refresh)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcCollection`3.EnsureCollectionInitialized()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcCollection`3.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ISfcCollection.EnsureInitialized()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo.get_Parameters()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.ExecuteDataProvider.AddParametersDataGridToDataBus()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.ExecuteDataProvider.AddToDataBus()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.PropertiesDataProvider.Initialize(ITaskManager taskManager, IPropertyDictionary properties)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskManager.InitializeTaskFormComponent(Object component, ITaskFormComponentInfo info)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskFormManager.InitializeTaskFormComponent(Object component, ITaskFormComponentInfo info)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskManager.InitializeTaskFormComponents(IList`1 taskFromComponentsInfo)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskFormManager.InitializeTaskFormComponents(IList`1 taskFromComponentsInfo)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskManager.Initialize(String moniker, IContext context, IList`1 taskFromComponents)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskFormManager.Initialize(String moniker, IContext context, ITaskFormInfo taskFormInfo)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskFormFactoryService.CreateTaskFormInstance(String taskFormMoniker, IContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ActionHandlers.ShowTaskUIDialogActionHandler.RunTaskForm(IContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ActionHandlers.DialogBasedActionHandler.RunTaskFormThread(Object contextObject)

Please help to fix it

Comment: What does this mean --> "from ssis to SSISD,"

Comment: hi , Thanks for looking into it.  I try to deploy the ssis pack to SSMS and create agent job to run the pack for me schedulely

Comment: Could be a MS bug.. Did you check if you have latest service pack installed?
Refer this and see if you need any hot fixes: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5987319e-a512-462c-b57f-035fb37528d3/error-an-entry-with-the-same-key-already-exists-system-occurs-when-trying-to-see-data?forum=sqltools

Comment: the pack run fine in VS 2016. just could not run it in SSMS ...I try use command prompt to run the pack, that works as well

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an error that one encounters when deploying SSIS packages having connection managers not in sync i.e. if a connection manager is changed as 'project connection manager' and this change is not reflected in the other packages using the same connection manager. Refer to the [link](http://bi-blogger.typepad.com/etlbi_blogger/2012/09/ssis-2012-item-with-same-key-as-already-been-added-error.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been occurred due to same connection name used for multiple packages.

Solution: Check which connections name are same for multiple packages .
Change the duplicate connection names and then Build and Deploy..

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I was not adding any key to any table. But I got this message without any pointer to what or where the problem was. I reconstructed my webpage having the problem in pieces and then I found it. This error comes when you have duplicate field names in the parameter to the GridView called DataKeyNames!
DatakeyNames is a parameter in the Gridview and you can find it just above where the "Columns" start.

I removed the duplicate field name in this parameter and the problem went away.